# Left aligned labels in descripton

Tags: beamer, horizontal-alignment, description

I have a description in a latex beamer file. Inside it, I use description with custom labels. My Problem is, that one point (the penultimate) is longer than the others. The labels are right aligned. Is there a way to get them left aligned? I didn't find a proper question here.
Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[handout]{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Analyse: Ziele laut Pflichtenheft}

\begin{description}
    \item[F10] Projektliste \pause
    % ...
    \item[D11-D14] Projektelemente speichern \pause
    \item[D20] Projekteinstellungen speichern \pause
\end{description}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: result of my code]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As `beamer` does not like the package `enumitem`, you will have to define your own "description item".

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass[handout]{beamer}
\defbeamertemplate{description item}{align left}{\insertdescriptionitem\hfill}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \frametitle{Analyse: Ziele laut Pflichtenheft}
        \setbeamertemplate{description item}[align left]
        \begin{description}
            \item[F10] Projektliste \pause
            % ...
            \item[D11-D14] Projektelemente speichern \pause
            \item[D20] Projekteinstellungen speichern \pause
        \end{description}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]